# change collectionViewCell Label font size when change orientation

Tags: swift, uilabel, orientation, font-size, custom-cell

I am displaying my data in a collection view. My app supports all orientation, landscape and portrait. I have custom collectionViewCell with label in it. My cell size is

```
CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width / 3 - 40, height: self.view.frame.width / 3 - 40)`
```

So, it increase the cell size when I rotate device to landscape mode.

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    guard let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout else {
        return
    }
    flowLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```

I have a label in cell

```
class ChannelViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

let label : UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.numberOfLines = 2
    label.font = UIFont(name: "ProRegular", size: 13)
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.textColor = UIColor.white
    label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    return label
}()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)


        addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|-5-[v0]-5-|", views: label)
        addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|-5-[v0]-5-|", views: label)
    }
}
```

I want to increase font size from **13** to **25** when landscape mode. Is it possible to update font size every time we rotate device ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
override func  layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape.boolValue {
        label.font = UIFont(name: "ProRegular", size: 25)
    } else {
        label.font = UIFont(name: "ProRegular", size: 13)
    } 
}
```

Comment: Awesome !! Thank you @Grzegorz Krukowski